# How can I change the language in Emacs when using ispell?

Tags: emacs, ispell

I would like to use the ispell-buffer command in Emacs. It uses the English language by default. Is there an easy way to switch to another dictionary (for example, another language)?

Comment: i would suggest all those answering this question to also inform how to add e.g. French to the set of ispell dictionaries, if it didn't get there during installation. I consider all the answers givenhere incomplete.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following command proposes a list of installed dictionaries to use:

```
M-x ispell-change-dictionary
```

Usually, `M-x isp-c-d` expands to the above also.

Comment: This sets the dictionary for the current session only. How can I set it as default for emacs ?

Comment: With the completion of `ispell-change-dictionary` you can check what strings are permissible for the variable `ispell-dictionary`. Choose the wanted one and customize `ispell-dictionary` (i.e., `M-x customize-option` `ispell-dictionary` and then input your wanted dictionary into the appropriate field).

Answer (score 33):

From the file ispell.el you may specify some options for the `ispell` commands. This happens by adding a section to the end of your file like this:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; ispell-check-comments: exclusive
;; ispell-local-dictionary: "american"
;; End:
```

Note the double semicolon marks the start of comments in the current mode. It should probably be changed to reflect the way your file (programming language) introduces comments, like `//` for Java.

Answer (score 22):

At the end of a LaTeX file you can use:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% ispell-local-dictionary: "british"
%%% End:
```

that will set the dictionary to be used just for that file.

Answer (score 14):

Use `M-x ispell-change-dictionary` and hit `TAB` to see what dictionary are available for you.

Then write the setting of default dictionary in your `.emacs`, and add a hook to start ispell automatically for you specific mode (if you want).

For instance, start ispell in AUCTeX automatically using British English (by default English dictionary is American English)

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode) ;start flyspell-mode
(setq ispell-dictionary "british")    ;set the default dictionary
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'ispell)   ;start ispell
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the language on a per-directory basis, you can add this to a `.dir-locals.el` file:

```
(ispell-local-dictionary . "american")
```

If you have no `.dir-locals.el` file already, it will look like this:

```
((nil .
   ((ispell-local-dictionary . "american")))
)
```

See the [emacs wiki page about directory variables](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience (f7) I added the following to my .emacs:

```lisp
(global-set-key [f7] 'spell-checker)

(require 'ispell)
(require 'flyspell)

(defun spell-checker ()
  "spell checker (on/off) with selectable dictionary"
  (interactive)
  (if flyspell-mode
      (flyspell-mode-off)
    (progn
      (flyspell-mode)
      (ispell-change-dictionary
       (completing-read
        "Use new dictionary (RET for *default*): "
        (and (fboundp 'ispell-valid-dictionary-list)
         (mapcar 'list (ispell-valid-dictionary-list)))
        nil t))
      )))
```

BTW: don't forget to install needed dictionaries. E.g. on debian/ubuntu, for the german and english dictionary:

```
sudo apt install aspell-de aspell-en
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to remap the C-\ key to automatically toggle between multiple languages *and* to change the input method to the corresponding language.
(derived from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45891514/17936582 )

```
;; Toggle both distionary and input method with C-\
(let ((languages '("en" "it" "de")))
  (setq ispell-languages-ring (make-ring (length languages)))
  (dolist (elem languages) (ring-insert ispell-languages-ring elem)))
  
(defun ispell-cycle-languages ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((language (ring-ref ispell-languages-ring -1)))
    (ring-insert ispell-languages-ring language)    
    (ispell-change-dictionary language)
    (cond
     ((string-match "it" language) (activate-input-method "italian-postfix"))
     ((string-match "de" language) (activate-input-method "german-postfix"))
     ((string-match "en" language) (deactivate-input-method)))))
(define-key (current-global-map) [remap toggle-input-method] 'ispell-cycle-languages)
```