# How do I change ispell private dictionary

Tags: emacs, ispell

I would like to do spell check on several files in a big project/repository and use a different private dictionary than my own. Such that I instead use a project dictionary and can later upload this for other users to use.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Chris is correct.  Here is just an example of what I use to switch between `aspell` personal dictionaries, and also `aspell` languages.  I use both `flyspell` and `ispell`.  The paths to the personal dictionaries would need to be adjusted according to the user specifications.

```
(defface ispell-alpha-num-choice-face
  '((t (:background "black" :foreground "red")))
  "Face for `ispell-alpha-num-choice-face`."
  :group 'ispell)

(defface ispell-text-choice-face
  '((t (:background "black" :foreground "forestgreen")))
  "Face for `ispell-text-choice-face`."
  :group 'ispell)

(defun my-ispell-change-dictionaries ()
"Switch between language dictionaries."
(interactive)
  (let ((choice (read-char-exclusive (concat
          "["
          (propertize "E" 'face 'ispell-alpha-num-choice-face)
          "]"
          (propertize "nglish" 'face 'ispell-text-choice-face)
          " | ["
          (propertize "S" 'face 'ispell-alpha-num-choice-face)
          "]"
          (propertize "panish" 'face 'ispell-text-choice-face)))))
    (cond
      ((eq choice ?E)
        (setq flyspell-default-dictionary "english")
        (setq ispell-dictionary "english")
        (setq ispell-personal-dictionary "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.aspell.en.pws")
        (ispell-kill-ispell)
        (message "English"))
      ((eq choice ?S)
        (setq flyspell-default-dictionary "spanish")
        (setq ispell-dictionary "spanish")
        (setq ispell-personal-dictionary "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.aspell.es.pws")
        (ispell-kill-ispell)
        (message "Español"))
      (t (message "No changes have been made."))) ))
```

Answer (score 5):

From Emacs, the variable `ispell-personal-dictionary` can be used to select your personal dictionary file:

> File name of your personal spelling dictionary, or nil. If nil, the
>   default personal dictionary, ("~/.ispell_DICTNAME" for ispell or
>   "~/.aspell.LANG.pws" for aspell) is used, where DICTNAME is the name
>   of your default dictionary and LANG the two letter language code.

On modern systems, Emacs' `ispell-` functions generally use [GNU `aspell`](http://aspell.net/), a

> a Free and Open Source spell checker designed to eventually replace Ispell

It isn't clear from your question whether everybody will be spell-checking through Emacs. Luckily, `aspell` supports a command-line option that works similarly:

```
--personal=<file>, -p <file>
    Personal word list file name.
```

Comment: After changing the `ispell-personal-dictionary` for a buffer that is already open with `flyspell` active, I use `ispell-kill-ispell` to get the new ispell session started.  When setting `ispell-personal-dictionary` before the buffer is loaded, there is no need to call `ispell-kill-ispell`.

Comment: @lawlist:   Running `ispell-kill-ispell` is not enough to force `ispell` to reload a new `ispell-personal-dictionary` that has been set.  Restarting emacs will force `ispell` to use a new personal dictionary, but this should not be necessary.  Any ideas on how to change personal dictionary while remaining in the same emacs 28 editor session?

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my init.el file, which works great for me
(found at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell)

```
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
(setq ispell-list-command "list")


(let ((langs '("spanish" "british" "french")))
  (setq lang-ring (make-ring (length langs)))
  (dolist (elem langs) (ring-insert lang-ring elem)))
(defun cycle-ispell-languages ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((lang (ring-ref lang-ring -1)))
    (ring-insert lang-ring lang)
    (ispell-change-dictionary lang)))
```

I've set a key combination to cycle from one dictionary to another

```
(global-set-key [M-f6] 'cycle-ispell-languages)
```